# Can't post variable to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to send a variable to PHP using JavaScript but I don't get any response whatsoever. Any ideas?

PHP/HTML:

```
    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="dashmenu.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <?php
        $selection = $_POST['selection'];
        if($selection == 'profile'){
      ?>
      <p> it works
      <?php
        }
      ?>

      <button id="button"> profile </button>
    </body>
```

JS file (dashmenu.js):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var menuSelection = "profile";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'dashboard.php',
        data: {selection: menuSelection},
        success: function(response) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: You might want to add a check to make sure that `$_POST['selection']` is actually set first so you don't get a notice if it isn't. You could do something like `if(isset($_POST['selection'])){ $selection = $_POST['selection']; }`

Comment: You're using the same file as destination of your request, therefore the result will have all html it haves. I think you want on the content inside the condition. So you should put that php snippet into another php file and do the request to it.

Comment: I am expecting to get an alert saying "success" at least, but the idea is that you click on a button and by doing this you set variable menuSelection to "profile" and then using AJAX you send it to PHP variable $selection and then I can use it in order to do some operations.

Comment: add an error function with an alert for that so you can see the error `error: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }`

Comment: Not getting any errors, probably button doesn't even trigger any JS events.

Comment: Is the php/html code posted above part of your dashboard.php page? If so, remember that everything outputted by php will be sent to your ajax call as part of the response, including the html code (html, head, body, etc.)

Comment: Yes it is, but currently I see that I am not getting any response from JS file. I am clicking button but nothing happens.

Comment: Open up the browser console or developer tools and see what happens when you click the button, you should see the XHR (AJAX) request and response. If you see nothing your JavaScript probably isn't executing, either way the browser console should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

In your html file (let's say index.html) you could have:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  var menuSelection = "profile";

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "html",
    url: 'dashboard.php',
    data: {selection: menuSelection},
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    },error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Error: ' + errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

In your dashboard.php, you should ONLY have code that processes requests, and returns (echoes) the desired output:

```
<?php
    $selection = $_POST['selection'];
    if($selection == 'profile'){
        echo "It works";
    }else{
        echo "It failed";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#button').click(function() {
    var menuSelection = "profile";

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'dashboard.php',
    data: {selection: menuSelection},
    success: function(response) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

});

Run this in your console in your browser. 
Right-click > Console tab.
If you want to check whether this function has successfully bind to the button. If your browser returns you 'success' alert, meaning you include it wrongly I guess.

If nothing happen when you click, please include .fail() in your $.ajax()

Which will look like this:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'dashboard.php',
   data: {
    selection: menuSelection
    },
   success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
   },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

  }
 });
```